# Using type predicates to perform overload resolution?

Tags: c++, c++14

In C++14, suppose I have a set of `N` mutually-exclusive bool constexpr variable templates of one type template parameter:

```
template<typename T> constexpr bool P1 = ...;
template<typename T> constexpr bool P2 = ...;
.
.
.
template<typename T> constexpr bool PN = ...;
```

By mutually-exclusive we mean that for any two distinct integers `i` and `j` (in `[1..N]`) and any type T, `Pi<T> && Pj<T>` is false.

I want to define an overloaded function set of one parameter, consisting of `N` function definitions, such that a function call expression with an argument of type T will select the`ith` function if `Pi<T>` is true, or will fail to compile if there is no such `Pi`:

```
void f(T such that P1<T>) { defn1; }
void f(T such that P2<T>) { defn2; }
.
.
.
void f(T such that PN<T>) { defnN; }
```

What is the simplest way to implement this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use SFINAE:

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<P1<T>>
f(const T&t) { defn1(); }

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<P2<T>>
f(const T&t) { defn2(); }

// ...
```

The requirement is that for type `T`, only one `Pi<T>` is `true`.